# Material EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am new to Android but I have this working code:

```
final android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout Tlay=new 
android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout(MainActivity.this);
Tlay.setLayoutParams(new 

ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

linear1.addView(Tlay);
final android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText EditText1=new 
android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText(MainActivity.this);

EditText1.setHint("Material EditText");
EditText1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); Tlay.addView(EditText1);`
```

But now I want it to be outlined but I can't get it to work. I need it it to be written in Java without xml.

Comment: You cannot change the theme programmatically. Because themes are applied during creation of view.

Comment: why did you mean by "I want it to be outlined"?